# Checkbox filter not working

Tags: php

I have this code which I grabbed from StackOverflow, and I changed the form method form post to get and it is not working for me. When I check on the boxes the page gets refreshed and a query is called. However the query does not return any rows, even if I have rows in the table. Any ideas?

**The HTML:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.checkbox').on('change',function(){
        $('#form').submit();
    });
</script>
<form id="form" method="GET" action="">
    <h4>Condition</h4>
    <input type="checkbox" name="new" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_GET['new'])?' checked':'')?>/> New<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="used" class="checkbox" <?=(isset($_GET['used'])?' checked':'')?>/> Used<br/>
</form>
```

**The PHP:**

```
if (isset($_GET["new"])) {
    $arguments[] = "`condition` LIKE '%new%'";
} 
if (isset($_GET["used"])) {
    $arguments[] = " condition LIKE '%use%' ";
}   
if( ! empty($arguments)) {
    $str = implode(' or ',$arguments);
    $fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? and ? ORDER BY id desc");
    echo $mydb->error;
    $fetch->bind_param('ss', $username, $str);
    $fetch->execute();
    $result = $fetch->get_result();
    //$result->num_rows gives me 0 in this case
} else {
    $fetch = $mydb->prepare("select * from table where username = ? order by id desc");
    $fetch->bind_param('s', $username);
    $fetch->execute();
    $result = $fetch->get_result();
    //this one works
}
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //echo some rows.
}
```

Comment: Was it working before you changed it from POST to GET? Are you sure you are opening the database properly? What does the query look like when you put all the parameters in - in particular, are you sure the quotes are right around the `or`? It looks dodgy.

Comment: @Floris the first time it worked and then I changed it to get cos I didn't like the confirm box every time I try to reload the page. I changed it back to post but it didn't work. The second query works correctly so the database is correct, and I have rows in the table for sure.

Comment: Why do you do the whole thing with `$arguments[]` as an array? What if you leave the new/used thing out - does it work then?

Comment: @user3006683 no errors, just no row is returned...Floris I found it like that from other answer here. if remove the arguments from the query it works yeah.

Comment: You should `echo $str`. I think there is (at least) a problem with the quoting (you have back ticks around `\`condition\`` in the first expression but not the second). Since you only have three configurations (no box checked, one box checked, or two boxes checked), maybe you can construct the queries without the second `?`.

Comment: @Floris I removed the `?` and changed the query to `$fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? and ".$str." ORDER BY id desc");` then it worked. So just to be sure will there be any be sql injection worry to `$str` as I am not accepting from the user? I have no idea how to replace it with `?` and bind it so I will be using the first method.

Comment: Your Javascript is missing a closing `});` for the `$(function(){`.

Comment: Since your `str` does not come from the user, I don't see how it would generate a problem with injection. But I am no expert… If your string was something like "condition LIKE ?", it would also be OK - it would protect against possible injection.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly long winded solution (doesn't really tell you what is wrong but may work):

```
if (isset($_GET["new"])  && !isset($_GET["used"])) {
   $fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? and condition LIKE '%new%' ORDER BY id desc");
} 
if (!isset($_GET["new"])  && isset($_GET["used"])) {
   $fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? and condition LIKE '%use%' ORDER BY id desc");
} 
if (isset($_GET["new"])  && isset($_GET["used"])) {
   $fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? and condition LIKE '%use%' or condition LIKE '%new%' ORDER BY id desc");
}
if (!isset($_GET["new"])  && !isset($_GET["used"])) {
   $fetch = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM table where username = ? ORDER BY id desc");
}

echo $mydb->error;

$fetch->bind_param('s', $username);
$fetch->execute();
$result = $fetch->get_result();
```

**update**

My daughter tells me that the real problem with your prepared statement is your attempt to put the name of a column into the query - you need to have `condition LIKE` in the prepared statement, and only add the value `'%new%'` or `'%use%'` where the question mark is… The prepared statement prepares the columns for selection.  So you would have to have at least three different prepared statements (none, one, two conditions) - you could generate these dynamically, or use the above to make your life simpler.